# Getting Probabilities from a file of counts

Tags: unix, math, awk, terminal

I have a bunch of files with lines that look like this

```
 54 apples
  7 oranges
  1 bananas
```

I'd like to get probabilities of each of these. That is, I want to have the following:

```
 0.87 apples
 0.11 oranges
 0.02 bananas
```

I can easily awk for a sum for each file individually

```
awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}' input.txt
```

But I'm wondering how to compute probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is canonical `awk` and doesn't store the file in memory:

`awk 'FNR==NR { sum += $1; next; } { printf "%.2f %s\n", $1/sum, $2 }' input.txt{,}`

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to run through the file twice, you'll need to store all the rows in memory.

```
awk '{sum += $1; line[NR,1] = $1; line[NR,2] = $2} END{for(i=0; i<NR; i++) print line[i,1]/sum, line[i,2]}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

may change the order

```
awk '{n[$2]=$1} END {for (fruit in n) printf("%.2d %s\n", n[fruit]/NR, fruit)}' file
```

or to preserve the order

```
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < file)" '{$1 = sprintf("%.2d", $1/lines}; print' file
```